# Javascript - object keys / values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, key, key-value

i want to know if i can set the same `value` for multiple `keys` in the following:

1. *React functional component state:*

```
const [state, setState] = useState(
key1: 'same-value',
key2: 'same-value',
key3: 'same-value'
);
```

2. *React class component state:*

```
state = {
 key1: 'same-value',
 key2: 'same-value',
 key3: 'same-value'
};
```

3. *Javascript object*:

```
const state = {
 key1: 'same-value',
 key2: 'same-value',
 key3: 'same-value'
};
```

I want to know if something like this is possible:

```
const state = {
 state1, state2, state3: 'same-value';
};
```

Comment: `state.state1 = state.state2 = state.state3 = 'same-value';` this is the only way that comes to my mind.

Comment: What is the use-case you're after?

Comment: `JSON.parse('{' + '"state,'.repeat(30).split(',').map(function(v, i, a){return v ? v + ++i : null}).join('":"same-value",').slice(0, -1) + '}')` :-D

Comment: @Lain [get with the times](https://jsbin.com/zatixofeji/edit?js,console)

Comment: @VLAZ: Going with time makes me feel old :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to know if something like this is possible

Not in an object literal, no. You can do it after creating the object:

```
const state = {};
state.key1 = state.key2 = state.key3 = 'same-value';
```

Or you could make `key2` and `key3` accessor properties for `key1`, meaning they'd track its value (change `key1`, and you see the change in `key2` and `key3`), because although using them looks like a simple property access, in fact it's a function call.

```
const state = {
    key1: 'some-value',
    get key2() { return this.key1; },
    get key3() { return this.key1; }
};
console.log(state.key1); // 'some-value'
console.log(state.key2); // 'some-value'
console.log(state.key3); // 'some-value'
```

I'm not suggesting that, just noting it's possible.

Comment: Ok thank you, another great lesson learned from stack community :)